# For a machine learning or NLP application -- Google App Engine vs Heroku vs App-fog

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, heroku, machine-learning, appfog

I have tried basic web applications on all the above three. If I were to rank them by convenience or freedom they provide then:

1. Google App Engine
2. App Fog
3. Heroku

But when the application domain became large the ranking actually changed. I am having huge troubles in using `sklearn`, `nltk` or `gensim` on GAE.

I am not very much experienced with Heroku and probably that is why I am having troubles in debugging errors where as GAE provides a console that really helps in debugging.

As far as app-fog is concerned it is pretty direct and to the point. But again what I noticed was that when I shared the link of the web-app almost everywhere it was being blocked by antivirus/firewalls!

Or maybe I am going wrong somewhere !

I need some suggestions please

Comment: I don't have enough experience with any of the three to make this a definitive answer, but I don't think those options are what you want for an ML application. They're mostly for web services -- make a request, get a response, many times per second. For long-running and CPU intensive tasks, I think you want something like Google *Compute* Engine or Amazon EC2 that aren't so tightly focused towards serving HTTP requests.

Comment: @deong This means that things like recommendation engines and similar application are better to be deployed on GCE or Amazon EC2 ?

Comment: Someone else can probably give you a more authoritative answer, but I believe the idea is that you'd use GAE to host the user-facing site, and connect it up to a GCE instance to do the heavy computation behind the scenes to train your model. If you were hosting this yourself, you wouldn't run your heavy machine learning code on your webserver; you'd run that on a cluster somewhere. GAE=web server and GCE=compute cluster.

Answer (score 0):

How are you using sklearn, nltk, or gensim? You may want to consider a platform designed for high performance scientific computation, such as [PiCloud](http://www.picloud.com).